# newbie: performing queries on collection of results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: projects and todos. In the projects index, I want to show an overview of projects, consisting of the project name and the number of todo items in the project with status "do", "doing", or "done". (eg: do:12 | doing:2 | done:25 ). In my projects controller, i can retrieve all projects, but i additionally need to find out how many todo items with each status are involved in each project. I have fixed this by defining additional database queries in the project index view:

```
Todo.where("project_id = ?", project.id).where("status = ?", "done").count)
```

This does not seem the right (MVC) way to solve this. What would be a better way? How can i perform additional queries on subsets of a collection of results.

I have tried to include all relevant code below:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :todos,  dependent: :destroy
end


class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_list
belongs_to :project
end
```

The schema for the models are:

```
create_table "projects", force: true do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
 end

 create_table "todos", force: true do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.string   "description"
   t.string   "status"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.integer  "position"
   t.integer  "project_id"
  end
```

the projects controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
   @projects = Project.all

  end
```

Comment: thanks for three quick & great answers. I accepted Slaweks's answer because of the attention to performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use additional columns for counters.

```
create_table "projects", force: true do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.integer "doing_counter"
   t.integer "done_counter"
 end
```

After that I would use callbacks, after_save and after_destroy on Todo model

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_list
  belongs_to :project
  after_save :update_counters
  after_destroy :update_counters
  def update_counters
       self.project.update_attribute(:doing_counter, self.project.todos.where('status=?', 'doing').count)
       self.project.update_attribute(:done_counter, self.project.todos.where('status=?', 'done').count)
  end
end
```

== performance tunning

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_list
  belongs_to :project
  after_create :update_counters
  after_update :update_counters_if_changed
  after_destroy :update_counters

  def update_counters_if_changed
       update_counters if status_changed?
  end

  def update_counters
       self.project.update_attribute(:doing_counter, self.project.todos.where('status=?', 'doing').count)
       self.project.update_attribute(:done_counter, self.project.todos.where('status=?', 'done').count)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Slawek, thanks for your solution. You mentioned performance issues with the other solution. Is that due to the number of database queries that are needed?

Comment: Yes, imagine that you have 50 projects on page, in that case you will need 3*50 count queries from other solution, or at least 50 if you use grouping and group count query. With my solution you can also sort projects by active tasks in effective way

Comment: hi, i've tried you solution and it works great. I am curious about the perfomance though. Doesn't the update_counters function introduce a lot of additional queries?

Comment: Depends how many times you will change Todo model, but regarding to structure - name and description will be set during creation, so you will only change position or status, this won't affect performance.

Comment: On the other hand, if you have model that changes frequently, you can use additional after_create method using update_counters, and different method for after_update using status_changed? to run queries only when status field is updated / I updated my post using also this approach

Answer (score 1):

The cleaner way would be to make a scopes

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_list
belongs_to :project
scope :do, -> { where(status: 'do') }
scope :doing, -> { where(status: 'doing') }
scope :done, -> { where(status: 'done') }
end
```

and from Project

```
project.todos.do.count
project.todos.doing.count...
```

Comment: thanks, that works great as well. I'm struggling to work out which answer to accept, since i've got three great answers within minutes.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this in your `project` model

```
def todo_count(type)
  #get todos of a given status
  todo = self.todos.where("status = ?", type.to_s)
  #count them
  todo.count
end
```

and call it in your view like this:

```
<%= @project.todo_count(do) %> #to get the count of `do` items
```

Comment: there will be performance problem with more projects with your solution

Comment: @Jelle, please upvote or check my answer if it's helped you, but take a look at the other answers first, Slawek and Techvineet also have good solutions

Comment: @dax: thanks. I'm not sure which answer to accept, since they all work great. But i won't forget to accept one of them.